# Why does the range of datatype number in oracle database is 38?

Tags: oracle, sqldatatypes

I read oracle docs that the range of datatype "number" in database is 38, and that is maximum range.

I google it and cant find anything except 38 is laws of karma, guardian angels...

Would you mind explaining why the range of number is 38?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is **precision** (not related to *karma* nor *angels* :)).

[Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6) says that number's format is `NUMBER [ (p [, s]) ]` :

> Number having precision p and scale s. The precision p can range from 1 to 38. The scale s can range from -84 to 127. Both precision and scale are in decimal digits. A NUMBER value requires from 1 to 22 bytes.

Precision is number of digits in a number. For example, number `123.45` has `5` digits so its precision is `5`.

Scale is number of digits to the right of decimal point; in this example, it is `45` which makes `2` digits so scale is `2`.

It means that (if we suppose that numbers will look like that) table you'd create would look as

```
create table (some_value   NUMBER (5, 2));   --> precision 5, scale 2
```

If you violate precision, Oracle will raise an error. You can, on the other hand, violate scale - in that case, Oracle will round that value.